# ¿Cómo llamar un Intent desde un Activity referido en otro?

Tags: android, activity

En el `ActivityB` quiero llamar al `ActivityC`, haciendo referencia al `ActivityA`.

Este es el código en el `ActivityB`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.class, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas hacer referencia a otra `Activity`, lo que se necesita es el contexto, que puede ser de la aplicación o la Actividad, de esta forma puedes abrir la `Activity` que deseas,  en este caso `ActivityC`:

```
//Usando contexto de la aplicación.
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
//Usando contexto de la aplicación.
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Si estas en `ActivityB` y deseas abrir `ActivityC`, puedes usar la referencia de la `Activity` en la que te encuentras, en este caso `ActivityB` :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Pero **no puedes usar la referencia de otra Activity en la cual no te encuentras**, por ejemplo estando en `ActivityB` y deseas abrir `ActivityC`, deseas usar `ActivityA` como referencia:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityC.class); // *Incorrecto!
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Es que no necesito el contexto de la Activity B, necesito es que lo llame la ActivityA

Comment: Quieres que cargue que Activity? si el objetivo es abrir ActivityC para que deseas ActivityA?

Comment: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57828/abrir-activity-creado-anteriormente-sin-recargarlo   por eso lo necesito asi

Comment: @SergioAndresMorenoHerrera revisa lo que agregue en la respuesta de la pregunta que indicas.

Answer (score 0):

Si te entiendo bien por tu referencia a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57828/abrir-activity-creado-anteriormente-sin-recargarlo), necesitas la referencia a `ActivityA` para asegurarte de llamar a la misma actividad en vez de crear más que una instancia. Si eso es el caso, no necesitas ninguna referencia, solamente tienes que definir el [modo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) correcto para tu `Activity`: `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

En un `Intent` puedes usar el flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` para garantizar lo mismo.

Este modo de arranque causa que en el caso que ya tienes una actividad de esta clase en el *backstack*, que no se crea una nueva, pero se mueve la actividad existente a primer plano, llamando a `onNewIntent(Intent intent)`.

Otras maneras de manejo propio de referencia a actividades pausados o inactivos trabajan contra el sistema en el sentido que Android gestiona el ciclo de vida de las actividades por uso de memoria, así no es una buena idea de mantener referencias a la instancia de una actividad en concreta.