# Abrir Activity creado anteriormente sin recargarlo

Tags: android

Activity A llama Activity B and C.

```
Intent intent_mapa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent_mapa.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent_mapa);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

luego Activity C calls me to Activity D.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity D llama a ActivityB sin recargar el WebView, ActivityB tiene un WebView y no necesito que me recargue la url.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Cuando se orpime atras abrimos nuevamente la Activity D.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityD.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(intent);
    return false;
}
```

el problema es que se me abre la Activity B al menos 2 veces por que se llama desde la Activity A y la Activity D.

Como hacer para que asi se llame desde diferentes Activity me abra solo una vez????

Comment: OK deseas asegurar que de la Activity solo se abra una sola instancia.

Comment: Si, por que si la abro desde 2 activity diferentes, me abre 2 instancias de la misma

Comment: Ok usa la propiedad android:launchMode="singleInstance" revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Como hacer para que asi se llame desde diferentes Activity me abra
>   solo una vez????

cuando definas tu `Activity` dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml` define la propiedad

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```

con esto obligarías a que solo se cree una sola instancia de la Activity.

Comment: Porque no usas singleTop? Evita un par de problemas...